# Relative path to Bundle in Twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have got standard Extend in Twig file:

```
{% extends 'AcmeMyBundle:Layout:defaultLayout.html.twig' %}
```

Can I call this template file by relative name of bundle?
eg.

```
{% extends '.:Layout:defaultLayout.html.twig' %}
            ^
            // relative 'dot'
```

Like in dir paths: "./relative/path/to/file.ext"

Comment: You can try it, and you'll know whether you can call it or not.

Comment: Nope but take a look at twig namespaces: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/namespaced_paths.html

Comment: Not without custom code and surely trying it would have taken less time than writing this question.

Comment: So, in app/config/config.yml i can add custom paths

Comment: I'm curious what a practical use case for that would be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just edit Config.yml file:

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    # ...
    paths:
        "%kernel.root_dir%/../src/acme/myBundle/Resources/views": foo_bar
```

And then you can have got access to relative path - you can simply change the path in config.yml instead in every include lines.

```
# view.html.twig
{% include '@foo_bar/Layout/defaultLayout.twig' %}
```